# Should i run a Background Service in android oreo?

Tags: android

//In some Oreo Devices i have seen crashes. and also there are some limitations after api level 26

```
    MediaPlayer player;

    public int onStartCommandd(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run services but only in the foreground (meaning you should provide a notification to the user that you are running your service)

for better understanding and different aspect of this matter please check out the official guide on [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

you can also make use of [Media Session Comapt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat) to provide easier media controls to the user

happy coding